# Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, alfresco-share, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

I am using Pentaho Data Integration 7.1.

I am not able to see default jobs in the Pentaho Data Integration.

can anyone help me with this?
Regards.

Comment: your question is not clear, can you please rephrase it..

Answer (score 0):

Although, the question is not clear.

I am using PDI 7.1 CE version and my default ETL job& transformation location is "/data-integration/samples" folder.